# How do I use the word "dare" correctly?

Tags: grammaticality

I just overheard a conversation between two foreign students and one of them was complaining abot something like this: *"I attend every single class while my classmates skip whole days and dare I not share my notes with them , I suddenely become the meanest person in the world."*

I'm not sure if I caught it properly, but this **dare I not** thing got me thinking. Is this correct grammatically? Or how else would you put it? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I dare say there are a number of different senses of the word.  What you quote is idiomatically archaic in the US, but grammatical.

Comment: It is correct to use *and dare I not share* as an rewording, with the meaning of *and if I dare to not share*.

Comment: It is indeed correct, but for quite some speakers it may seem (slightly?) archaic.

Comment: See also [a search of this site for 'dare i not'](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dare+i+not+)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to contemporary ears like archaic English.

The usual way of expressing this would be

> and if I dare to not share my notes with them, I suddenly become the meanest person in the world.

In Early Modern English grammar, you could use inversion instead of an *if* clause to create a counterfactual.

> I could not love thee, dear, so much, loved I not honor more.

In contemporary English, this would be

> I could not love you, dear, so much, if I didn't love honor more.

We still use inversion instead of *if* clauses for past tense modals and auxiliary verbs:

> I could have borne the shade, had I not seen the sun.

We don't use inversion instead of *if* with present tense modals or non-counterfactual conditionals. So we don't say

> *I will help you, can I find the time,

although

> I would help you, could I find the time,

is grammatical (if a little old-fashioned sounding).

I don't believe people ever did this; I haven't found any use of inversion for non-counterfactual conditional clauses (although maybe I didn't look hard enough).

Here, *dare* is indeed a semi-modal. But it's not a past tense modal and this isn't a counterfactual conditional clause.

So I don't think this would have been grammatical in Early Modern English.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'm new to this site and don't really know how to give thumbs up and suc, but thank you all who answered!

Answer (score 0):

The object of the "dare", here, simply includes a negative possibility; it hasn't been grammatically changed in any way. The only real point of interest is the inversion of the verb and subject, "dare I" rather than "I dare", to give a conditional mood.

For instance, you could equate the negative expression to one that simply uses an embedded negative, such as "dare I refuse to lend him my notes", which would in turn equate to "if I dared (to) refuse to lend him my notes".

It doesn't sound particularly archaic to me, but I probably read more pre-modern English literature than most people.